# Java. Division of input so that number will be divided into 3 equal parts but trick is in description of question

Tags: java

Let's say I have number x=6 I want to divide this number in such a way that I can run 3 loops based on the 1st, 2nd and 3rd part.

For example: x=6 then 1st loop (1-2), 2nd loop (3-4), 3rd loop (5-6).

Example 2: x=3000 then 1st loop (1-1000), 2nd loop (1001-2000), 3rd loop (2001-3000). I don't want to put manually because x can be any "even" number.

x will be number that can be equally divided like 3,6,9,12,15,18 .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by the following code. There is no validation as you said the number would be divisible

```
int x; //your value
int step = x/3;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int j=(step*i)+1;j<=step*(i+1);j++){
       //do something with j
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will run the the inner loop 3 times and the inner loop will run x/3 times.

```
public static void executeLoop(int multiple) {
    int interval = multiple / 3;
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        start = i * interval;
        end = start + interval;
        for (int j = start; j < end; j++) {
            System.out.printf("i: %d, j: %d\n", i, j);
        }

    }
}
```